# Windows can't open files (pictures, video), says it can't find the file even though I clicked it directly

Tags: windows-10

I can open a picture in edit, just can't open it directly?!?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHhaF.jpg]

Comment: Which image viewer have you set as the default? See if resetting Photos app as the default, via Control Panel > Default Programs > Set your default programs.

Comment: OK, I looked.  The problem is that TWINUI doesn't work (and has been set as the default for most picture & video file types).  I can change that, but advice on how to fix the error?

Comment: TWINUI is actually the Photos app. I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Re-register/Reinstall the Photos app using PowerShell commands:
Open PowerShell (Run as Administrator), and execute the following command:

```
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Windows.Photos -allusers | select PackageFullName
```

Note down the Package name shown. For example, if the Package name is listed as Microsoft.Windows.Photos_16.302.8200.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe, execute the next command as follows:

```
Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_16.302.8200.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode
```

As of now the Store apps are still buggy.. often requiring the user to run the PowerShell commands. For Desktops, better option is to enable the hidden [Windows Photo Viewer](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/restore-windows-photo-viewer-windows-10/) and set it as default.